# A noob programmers first try

Tags: javascript

Hey so I am currently trying to get a plane to move on a window, from each extremity to the other, following this order: from upper left to upper right, from upper right to lower right, from lower right to lower left followed by lower left to upper left. This project is forced to have an accelerated movement from the upper right to the lower right and from the lower left to the upper left. I used a switch case just like I would in java but it doesn't seem to be stopping when the plane hits the windows max width.. any help would be appreciated ...

```
    var ctx;
var img;
var larg = 1200;
var alt = 560;
var xAviao = 0;
var yAviao = 0;
c = 1

// Parâmetros do movimento acelerado
var x0 = 0;
var y0 = 0;
var v0 = 0;
var a = 120;    // 120 px/s2
var t = 0;

function init() {
canvas = document.getElementById("cvs");
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.setAttribute("width", larg);
canvas.setAttribute("height", alt);

img = new Image();
img.src = "aviao.png";

gameLoop();
}

function gameLoop() {
window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
update();
render();
}

function update() {
var direction = 1;
if( xAviao > ( larg - img.Width ) )         
    {
        y0 = 0;
        a = 120;
        t = 0;
        xAviao = ( larg - img.Width );
        direcao = 2;
    }
    else if ( yAviao > alt - img.Height ) 
    {
        yAviao = alt - aviao.Height;
        direction = 3;
    }    
    else if ( xAviao < 0 ) 
    {            
        xAviao = 0;
        t = 0;
        y0 = yAviao;
        a= -120;                         
        direction = 4;
    }
    else if ( yAviao < 0 ) 
    {            
        yAviao = 0;
        direction = 1;
    }            


switch(direction){
    case 1:

        xAviao +=10 ;
    console.log(c);
    break;
    case 2:            
        t += 1/60;  // time increases 60 seconds per 60 frames  
        yAviao = Math.floor( y0 + v0*t + a*t*t );        
    break;
    case 3:
        xAviao -= 10;        
    break;
    case 4:                 
        t += 1/60;  // time increases 60 seconds per 60 frames            
        yAviao = Math.floor( y0 + v0*t + a*t*t );                
    break;                            
    }
}

function render() {
// Retângulo do fundo
ctx.fillStyle = "#FFA060";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(0,0,larg,alt);
ctx.fill();

// Desenha o avião
if(img != undefined)
    ctx.drawImage(img, xAviao, yAviao);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have a simple typo in the first if statememt in the `update` function. Shouldn't `direcao = 2` be `direction = 2`?